# Why doesn't this link_to url helper update the boolean record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, urlhelper

Thanks in advance.  Tried to provide as much detail as possible.  Attempting to create a link that updates a boolean record in a database.  Basically, someone can mark a gift as purchased without going a separate form.  I've done this in the past with post and delete links without problems. :post not accepted by controller (only

I get: 'Gift was successfully updated.' message after clicking but the database is not updated.

```
<%= link_to "Mark Purchased", user_gift_path(@user, gift, :purchased => true), :method => :put %>
```

Controller: Uses InheritedResources Gem

```
class GiftsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # redirects to gifts upon update
  def update
    update!{ collection_url }
  end

end
```

Works in Console

```
>> g=Gift.last
=> #<Gift id: 32, subject: "Birdbath", note: "Saw this at store ", created_at: "2010-01-09 18:52:48", updated_at: "2010-01-09 20:10:24", photo_file_name: "Birdbath.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 7203, photo_updated_at: "2010-01-09 18:52:48", user_id: 18, store_id: 2, sku: "111390", product_url: "http://www.store.com/birdbath-kyoto-greensto...", price: 130.95, purchased: false, size_color: "blue">
>> g.purchased=true
=> true
>> g.save
=> true
```

Server:

```
Processing GiftsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-01-09 15:18:55) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"***", "id"=>"32", "purchased"=>"true", "user_id"=>"18"}
  User Columns (1.4ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
  User Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 18) 
  Gift Columns (1.2ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `gifts`
  Gift Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `gifts` WHERE (`gifts`.`id` = 32 AND (`gifts`.user_id = 18)) 
  SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
  Store Columns (1.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `stores`
  Store Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE (`stores`.`id` = 2) 
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  SQL (0.1ms)   COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/18/gifts
Completed in 56ms (DB: 0) | 302 Found [http://localhost/users/18/gifts/32?purchased=true]
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET NAMES 'utf8'
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0


Processing GiftsController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-01-09 15:18:56) [GET]
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"18"}
  User Columns (1.4ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
  User Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 18) 
  Gift Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `gifts` WHERE (`gifts`.user_id = 18) 
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering gifts/index
  Gift Columns (1.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `gifts`
  Store Columns (1.2ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `stores`
  Store Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE (`stores`.`id` = 2) 
  User Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`remember_token` = '***') LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE (`stores`.`id` = 2) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 18) 
Completed in 65ms (View: 47, DB: 5) | 200 OK [http://localhost/users/18/gifts]
```

Answer (score 1):

Doh!

```
<%= link_to "Mark Purchased", user_gift_path(@user, gift, :gift => {:purchased => true}), :method => :put %>
```